# How to convert a url to a browser like url? ( ...%20... )

Tags: php, curl

I want to get data using CURL but I have a problem. When I set the url like this

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT name FROM page"; // continues
```

I do not have anything returned. When I copy the browser url, this is

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20name%20FROM%20page";
```

I get the results through CURL. I tried *htmlentities* and *htmlspecialchars* without luck.

What am I missing here?

```
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  $content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: has nothing to do with entitites or special chars, but a lot with urlencode/decode.

Comment: htmlentities and htmlspecialchars? URLs aren't HTML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would use `urlencode($string);` in the `curl_init();` or call the urlencode before and set it to a variable like so:

**example:**

```
<?php
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=';
$query = "SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id in(SELECT page_id, type FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me() AND type != 'APPLICATION' )&access_token=". $facebook->getAccessToken();
$ch = curl_init(urlencode($query));
$ch = $url.$ch;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

**php documentation:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

---

### incorrect usage of: [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

htmlspecialchars() is used to strip characters and sanitize data in the URI string. use urldecode to decode the %20's and such into their proper strings.

Conversely use urlencode($string); to convert spaces, slashes, ampersands and other elements into their respective URL friendly counterpart.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am having some difficulties though. This is my actual url `$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id in(SELECT page_id, type FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me()  AND type != 'APPLICATION' )&access_token=". $facebook->getAccessToken();`

Comment: so then you pass the query part (everything after `?q=`) to `urlencode();` and then concatenate the url and the query parameter together, and then pass it to curl. I have updated my answer to reflect an actual example.

Comment: Thank you Mike. It gave me an error because of the `&access_token=". $facebook->getAccessToken()`. I moved it into a new variable and added it in the `$url.$ch` and it works.

Answer (score 2):

What about [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

```
$url = urlencode($url);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am having some difficulties though. This is my actual url `$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id in(SELECT page_id, type FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me()  AND type != 'APPLICATION' )&access_token=". $facebook->getAccessToken();`

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
  $ch = curl_init(urlencode($url));
```